# Set up voice for Chinese Phoneme and Japanese Phoneme using SAPI IN C++

Tags: c++, mfc, sapi

How do I call Chinese voice in SAPI using c++? Is that possible?
I am working Text to Speech on MFC form which can able to speak in 3 major languages called English, Malay and Mandarin once user insert the input. I have done for the English part as SAPI has the library to call english lady voice. Having trouble to call mandarin and malay voices. Is that any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install Chinese (and Malay) TTS voices.  Windows installs the TTS voices as part of the language packs.  Microsoft doesn't have Malay TTS voices available.  [PortalGroove](http://www.portalgroove.com/voices/malay/) has a (preview, so probably not that great) Malay TTS voice; a quick web search didn't find any others (including commercial TTS voices).